# setInterval only running on 4 of my 5 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, setinterval

I have to make some table-cells blink based on their values, and apparently IE8 is still a thing, so I'm working on the fix for that..

Here's my function for adding the blink-effect:

```
function blinkForIE(element) {
    setInterval(function () {
        if (element.hasClass('IEBlink')) {
            element.removeClass('IEBlink');
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('IEBlink');
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

the class:

```
.IEBlink
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

This works for 4 of my 5 cells that should be blinking. I've debugged and checked taht the correct elements are getting passed to the `blinkForIE`-method and it adds the `setInterval`-thing for the first 4 elements but not the 5th..

Anyone knows why this might be happening? (I'm not sure what info might be needed, so if you need something else please comment and I'll add it when I can.)

**EDIT: still not sure what you guys need to see, but here's all the jquery**

```
var threshold = 100; //---THIS can be changed to what ever our threshold-difference should be.

$(document).ready(function () {
    var itemsIndex;
    var locationIndex;
    var locations = [""];

    $('#<%= gvKeying.ClientID %> tbody tr.GridHeader th').each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() === 'Items') {
            itemsIndex = $(this).index() + 1;       //Find the column index of the Items column (+1 for nth-child usage)
        }
        else if ($(this).html() === 'KeyingLocation') {
            locationIndex = $(this).index() + 1;    //And the same for KeyingLocation-column.
        }
    });

    $('#<%= gvKeying.ClientID %> tbody tr td:nth-child(' + locationIndex + ')').each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() === '&nbsp;') {
            //Do nothing.
        }
        else {
            locations.push($(this).html());     //Add all locations to an array
        }
    });
    locations = unique(locations);              //Make them unique
    locations.shift();                          //This just removes the first empty element.

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {    //Loop through all locations
        var values = [];
        var valuesToBlink = [];

        $('#<%= gvKeying.ClientID %> tbody tr').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('td:nth-child(' + locationIndex + ')').html() === locations[i]) {
                values.push($(this).find('td:nth-child(' + itemsIndex + ')').html());               //Make an array with all the values.
            }
        });
        values = getTop5(values);   //We just want the top 5 highest values.
        var firstBlinkVal = -1;

        for (var j = 0; j < values.length - 1; j++) {                       //Loop through the values.

            if (firstBlinkVal > -1 && compare(values[j], values[j + 1]) > -1) {
                firstBlinkVal = Math.min(firstBlinkVal, compare(values[j], values[j + 1]));
            }
            else if(compare(values[j], values[j + 1]) > -1){
                firstBlinkVal = compare(values[j], values[j + 1]);
            }
        }

        if (firstBlinkVal > -1) {
            for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
                if (values[j] >= firstBlinkVal) {
                    valuesToBlink.push(values[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        $('#<%= gvKeying.ClientID %> tbody tr').each(function () {                                  //Loop through all rows.
            if ($(this).find('td:nth-child(' + locationIndex + ')').html() === locations[i]) {      //If this row is the current location,
                var temp = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + itemsIndex + ')').html();                 //get the value for this row.
                if (jQuery.inArray(temp, valuesToBlink) > -1) {                                     //if we want this to blink,
                    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
                    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

                    if (msie > 0) {
                        blinkForIE($(this).find('td:nth-child(' + itemsIndex + ')'));               //make it blink for IE
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + itemsIndex + ')').addClass('blink_me');      //make it blink for everything else.
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

});

function blinkForIE(element) {
    var x = element.html();
    console.log(x);
    setInterval(function () {
        if (element.hasClass('IEBlink')) {
            element.removeClass('IEBlink');
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('IEBlink');
        }
    }, 100);
}

//This just compares two values and returns true if the diff is over our threshold.
function compare(val1, val2) {
    if (Math.abs(val1 - val2) > threshold) {
        return Math.max(val1, val2);
    }
    return -1;
}

//Returns a sorted array of the top5 highest values in the input-array.
function getTop5(values) {
    values.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a });
    while (values.length > 5) {
        values.pop();
    }
    values.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
    return values;
}

//Makes the values of the input unique.
function unique(list) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(list, function (i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can use `toggleClass()`

Comment: Can you add any markup or the code that is calling the blinkForIE() function? Additionally you may want to reconsider your approach to do this on individual elements.

Comment: Microsoft don't support ie8 anymore - they only support the latest browser: http://venturebeat.com/2016/01/12/microsoft-ends-support-for-ie8-ie9-ie10-and-windows-8/.  Also please consider adding more information to the question as in it's current form, we can only guess why your code isn't working

Comment: @Pete: Yeah, but the blasted thing still has ~7.5% global market share; higher in some sub-populations stuck on Windows XP (which Microsoft also doesn't support). Thankfully both are rapidly losing ground.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I've always worked to the principal, if you can't be bothered to upgrade then you don't deserve to have the full experience!  Besides if we give them a bad experience, it may finally force them to move on

Comment: @Pete: Well, given how most of us react to blinking things on web pages, maybe that's what Johan's trying to do! ;-)

Comment: @Tushar Thanks! The code looks nicer, but it still didn't solve my problem

Comment: 1. does it run ok in other browser?

Comment: 2. try `$(this.childNodes[itemsIndex-1])` instead of `$(this).find('td:nth-child(' + itemsIndex + ')')`

Comment: @PavelGatnar Yes, it works fine in other browsers. In other browsers I'm using css animation, and it works with no problem

Comment: @PavelGatnar made no difference =/ The weird thing is that if I debug it using my browsers developer console, I can see that all the values are passed to `blinkForIE()`, but only the first 4 actually get the blinking effect.

Comment: @Pete It's not really up to me. I'd like to just give the IE8-users the middle finger, but my boss want's me to make this work for IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call only 1 `setInterval` function, passing all cells to be animated.

```
function blinkForIE(elements) {
  setInterval(function(){
    elements.forEach(function(e){$(e).toggleClass('IEBlink')})
  }, 100);
}
```

resp.

```
function blinkForIE($elements) {
  setInterval(function(){
    $elements.toggleClass('IEBlink')
  }, 100);
}
```

(`elements` is Array, `$elements` is jQuery object)

The problem is, that `setInterval` must not execute the callback function, if there is no idle time slot at the execution time. It happens, when there are many executions within a small time interval.
You can troubleshoot this also using different offsets:

```
setTimeout(function(){setInterval(callback, 100)}, i*15)
```